# Turn off 'DataWedge', 'Wedge as Keys', etc.. Programatically in Android Studio for Scanner SDKs Honeywell, Datalogic, Zebra

Tags: android, android-studio, barcode-scanner, honeywell, keyboard-wedge

'DataWedge' services automatically place scan data in an 'inFocus' field like an EditText, However I would like this functionality turned off so I can place the data where I want

I have already tried searching the internet and trawling through the settings. Awaiting response from customer service

here is some code I tried for Datalogic which did not work

```
        var keywedge = KeyboardWedge(mBarcodeManager)
        //keywedge.enable = BooleanProperty(0)
        keywedge.enable.set(false)
```

Note. I have solved the Datalogic SDK, I only need help with Honeywell (I missed a step) here is the solution ;)

```
        var keywedge = KeyboardWedge(mBarcodeManager)
        keywedge.enable.set(false)
        try{
            keywedge.store(mBarcodeManager,false)
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Log.e(TAG, "Cannot disable Wedge", e)
        }
```

Comment: Can you expand (give detail example) of what you mean by "I can place the data where I want"? I would think you would change focus to the field you want before scan, otherwise don't use a KeyboardWedge module and just get the barcode value directly via SDK.

Comment: Hi I do use the SDK, however only Zebra seems to turn off DataWedge by default. 'Place data where I want' is already solved I can do this already, it's just annoying that the wedge will also place data in an in focus field. Also after hours of pulling hair I just solved the Datalogic one lolz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this one some time ago sorry for the lack of update

Honeywell

```
   //Simply claim the scanner
   try{
        barcodeReader?.claim()
   } catch (e: ScannerUnavailableException){
        e.printStackTrace()
   }
```

Datalogic

```
var keywedge = KeyboardWedge(mBarcodeManager)
keywedge.enable.set(false)
try{
    keywedge.store(mBarcodeManager,false)
}catch (e: Exception){
    Log.e(TAG, "Cannot disable Wedge", e)
}
```

Zebra

```
//Add the Data & Status Listeners then enable
scanner?.addDataListener(this)
scanner?.addStatusListener(this)
scanner?.enable()
```